# any drawback of using bitbucket/github as cloud storage?

Tags: cloud-storage, github

Technically it's OK to use such public version control system (svn, git, mercurial, etc) as cloud storage. But is it legal or is there any drawback of doing so?

Comment: CVS? Bitbucket is Mercurial and Github is Git.

Comment: @Tim wrong tagged, edited :)

Comment: @Tim: Considering that Bitbucket now supports Git and Github supports SVN, I wouldn't be too surprised if one of them gained CVS support (but hopefully only on April 1st).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **But is it legal?**

Only a lawyer can answer that. First you need to work out which jurisdiction applies. I see nothing obvious in GitHub's terms of service that say you can only use GitHub for collaborative software development. I am not a Lawyer.

> **is there any drawback of doing so?**

Well, if the business who run GitHub decide they don't like what you are doing, they can change their Terms Of Service and delete all your content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's legal, you might be violating their terms of service. (Disclaimer: i'm not a lawyer), but it would be a stupid thing to do.
Use something like Dropbox where it's **private** and you have 2GB of storage on the free plan.

Other alternatives:
box.net,
Microsoft SkyDrive

Comment: I've noticed that and bitbucket offers private project for free so that nobody(common users) finds it.